# Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

i am having an error in my Android Studio project. 
You have a screenshot with the code. [image]
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
It tells me, when i hover that " cannot resolve symbol .EasyFleet"

Comment: Your MainActivity is inside main->java but EasyFleet is part of androidTest->java. Please move EasyFleet to main->java. Maybe this will help.

Comment: That helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MainActivity is inside main->java but EasyFleet is part of androidTest->java. Please move EasyFleet to main->java.

Hope it helps.